# Why would this simple remoting example work on my laptop but not my desktop?

Tags: .net, remoting, typeloadexception

I was trying to create a remotable object and getting errors even though it seemed like everything was in order, so I decided to simplify and run a sample piece of code straight from Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx).

When I run this code I get a TypeLoadException when it calls CreateInstanceAndUnwrap().  However, I just tried it on my laptop and it worked fine.  Anybody have any clue why it would work on the laptop but not the desktop??  I just created a console app on each and copy/pasted the code below so I don't understand what would be different between the two.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class Worker : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void PrintDomain() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Object is executing in AppDomain \"{0}\"",
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName); 
    }
}

class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create an ordinary instance in the current AppDomain
        Worker localWorker = new Worker();
        localWorker.PrintDomain();

        // Create a new application domain, create an instance 
        // of Worker in the application domain, and execute code 
        // there.
        AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New domain");
        Worker remoteWorker = (Worker) ad.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
            "Worker");
        remoteWorker.PrintDomain();
    }
}
```

EDIT:  So, I just tried to create an instance of the type using the Activator in the local domain and even that gave me an error saying that it couldn't load file or assembly 'System.RuntimeType' or one of its dependencies.  Seeing as how that's an internal type to the .Net Framework that I couldn't keep it from deploying even if I wanted to, I'm quite baffled now.

EDIT:  There is no InnerException, but here's the Stack:

```
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at ConsoleApplication1.Example.Main(String[] args) in D:\Projects\Remoting\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 28
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Oh, and the exception reads:

```
{"Could not load type 'Worker' from assembly 'ConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.":"Worker"}
```

Also, I tried running this line of code:

```
var w = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Worker).GetType().FullName, "Worker");
```

and got a FileNotFoundException:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.RuntimeType' or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: @HansPassant No InnerException or I definitely would have posted that.  And I have no clue what to make of the stack so I didn't think about posting it, but hopefully you can see something helpful there.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, they are both on Framework 4 Client Profile

Comment: @HansPassant Even when I just try to use the Activator in the local domain it crashes (as noted in the last update on my post)

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, trust me I was always the guy who asked the questions the teacher couldn't figure out.  You're right about ': "Worker"' not being part of the exception, but when you click "View Detail" on the exception helper that pops up and copy it from there like I did then it adds that.  And I am as clueless as you on what the heck System.RuntimeType is doing in there, but it's there and that's why I'm here :/  I don't know what Fuslogvw.exe is but I'll find out and post it soon.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't see any settings to 'attach' the Assembly Binding Log Viewer to my app so my first assumption is that it has some kind of global hook and shows everything, but there are no entries in it even after running my app in the debugger.  I'm still researching this tool though so maybe I don't have it setup right yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your initial code, you are trying to instantiate an incomplete typename, and that code shouldn't work anywhere unless Worker has no namespace.  It should be:

```
var workerType = typeof(Worker);
Worker remoteWorker = (Worker) ad.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
            // Where Worker is defined (probably the same as current assembly in you case)
            workerType.Assembly.FullName,
            // Worker's *fully-qualified* typename, including the namespace 
            workerType.FullName);
```

Your local activation code is mistakenly calling `typeof(Worker).GetType().FullName` rather than `typeof(Worker).FullName`.

`typeof(Anything).GetType()` will always return `System.RuntimeType`

Comment: Okay, so the activation thing was a red herring then because I made a mistake on that.  However, the initial code is direct from Microsoft's website (from the link in my post) and it definitely does work as written on my laptop though not on my desktop.  I wish I knew why that was, but the code you provided here definitely works so I guess I can't complain :)

Comment: The MS sample code has no namespaces, I'll bet your Worker class at some point was put in a namespace and it stopped working, and the switch to a different machine was coincidental.  Possible?  The lack of FullName wouldn't matter if there is no namespace.

Comment: I just used the default Console App template and there's definitely a namespace.  I don't think it would even compile if it weren't in a namespace would it?

Comment: Yes, it would compile (the sample code on msdn and what you pasted have no namespaces.)  If there is no explicit namespace, code is put in the global:: namespace and doesn't need qualification unless there is a collision with another namespace.

Comment: Oops, you're absolutely right :)  I just went back and checked my laptop and when I copy/pasted there I control-a'd before I pasted, but on the desktop I didn't blow away the namespace.